# Get the observability of class methods in PHP

Tags: php, oop

The function [get_classs_methods](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) returns all methods of a class.

But, is there a function or technique to get the observability of these methods?

I want to list only the public methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value from [get_class_methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) depends on the scope you're calling it from; if you're calling it from outside the class, you'll only get the methods that are visible from the current scope. Calling it from a method inside the class will give you all the available methods from the class.

If you want more information or to query the class in a more detailed manner, you probably want to look at [using reflection and the getMethods method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php).